# Installing compat-libstdc++-33 on RHEL 7

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, rhel7

As part of an Oracle install I need to install the `compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3 (x86_64)` package. However no matter what variant of the package I try to install with yum, it can't be found

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx ~]# yum install compat-libstdc++-33
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, langpacks, rhui-lb
No package compat-libstdc++-33 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx ~]#
```

Am I missing a repo or something more obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the RHEL optional and/or extras channels.

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

Comment: I tried every thing but it worked for me Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Download package here:
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=compat-libstdc%2B%2B-33

for RHEL7, its under distribution: CentOS 7.2

or search on rpmfind.net